# Codeigniter error Missing argument

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've concatenated the id of the user and I would pass it as a paramater to my controller which is addquestion($id) but I keep getting these errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered  Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 1 for Questions::addquestion()
Filename: controllers/questions.php
Line Number: 49

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: id
Filename: controllers/questions.php
Line Number: 67

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048
Column 'question_user_id' cannot be null
INSERT INTO `questions` (`question_user_id`, `question`) VALUES (NULL, 'sdf')
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\webdev\askme\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

Here's my View:

```php
<h1>ASK USERS</h1>
<ul class="list_items">
<?php foreach ($users as $user):?>
    <li>
        <div class="list_name"><b><?php echo $user->username;?></b></div>
        <div class="list_body"><?php echo $user->register_date;?> </div>
        <div class="list_body"> 
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>questions/addquestion/<?php echo $user->id; ?>">Ask a question</a>
            <!--<?php //echo anchor(//'questions/addquestion/'.$user->id, //'Ask a question'); ?> -->
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

And here's my addquestion function in my controller:

```php
public function addquestion($id) // line 49 
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('question','Your Question','trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //Load view and layout
        $data['main_content'] = 'questions/add_question';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);  
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Validation has ran and passed  
        //Post values to array
        $data1 = array(   
            'question_user_id'      => $id,    
            'question'      => $this->input->post('question')
        );
       if($this->Questions_model->create_question($data1))
       {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('question_created', 'Question sent');
           // Redirect to index page with notification above
            redirect('home/index');
       }
    }
}
```

please help me, i dont know what's wrong

Comment: the error is not in the code you pasted... its in the controller where you give the request param (or whereever $id is coming from) to the addquestion method.

Comment: Where is code for line no  49?

Comment: `public function addquestion($id)`
that's line 49

Comment: it seems like the $id is not set properly.

Comment: I dont understand, because if I echo the $id, I get a value. But when I use it as value for my db field, it returns empty..

Comment: Did you get the value of $id inside your function?

Comment: Yes I've tried placing the value of the $id into a variable, but still doesn't work

Comment: I am facing with same issue, did you get any help @user3400419

Answer (score 0):

you are sending null values to your db field and it's can not be NULL or try to make your `question_user_id` can be NULL
so your `$id` can not be empty it's required any value so use check for this

```
 else {
       if(empty($id)) 
          redirect('home'); // redirect to any page
        $data1 = array(   
            'question_user_id' => $id,    
            'question' => $this->input->post('question')
        );
```

Comment: if I echo only the $id, I get a value. Why is that, I can't use the $id as value for my 'question_user_id' db field?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
      public function addquestion($id='')
```

Comment: I got the $id part, now I cant add the question, it won't redirect to my view.. Thank you, though